# Kernel 4.15 through 4.16 does not compile on hp2000 laptop with and e-300

Tags: laptop

**Hardware**:

HP2000 Laptop, AMD E-300

Linux kernel 4.14.34 compiles fine.

Starting with 4.15.0 through 4.16.3, kernel does not compile. Using Debian 9 Stretch.

**Question**:

Is AMD E-300 no longer supported?

Is there a list of no longer supported hardware?

Is there a roadmap of hardware that will not be supported?

Comment: Can you describe more precisely how it fails?

Comment: Provide logs of what's happening when you try ot compile it, and you might get some help. In it's current form this question is unanswerable.

Comment: Also that cpu is completely supported in the newer kernels however you maybe missing a kernel configuration option that you need - the logs would show this.

Answer (score 0):

Actually if it is AMD Fusion or something close/compareable you can check here -

> https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7332/implications-of-linux-support-for-amd-fusion-apus

That's all i know for now.

Will add extras in the comments if i find something or learn something new

Comment: Still trying to compile a kernel greater than 4.14. Have the HP 2000 with E-300 AMD processor. Put a spare drive in my HP G6 with Intel i3. Am using Debian 9 Stretch. Kernel 4